# Is there a function that can get values and keys from a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I want to create a function that returns the key if the user entered the value and the value if the user entered the key

I wrote this code, but is there a way to do this using dictionary?

```
def select(word):
    if word == 'Hello':
        return 'Hola'
    elif word == 'Hola':
        return 'Hello'
```

Comment: Do you need O(1) or not? Because you can get O(1) if you're willing to store it as two dictionaries as a reverse of each other.

Comment: No there isn't. You can check keys for membership via `if key in dictionary`, but must do the reverse lookup manually — and there nothing that says a value can't itself be a container of some sort.

Comment: @Martheen: It's not always possible to have a "reverse" dictionary if the values of the original aren't hashable — plus it has to be constructed each time it's needed.

Comment: Don’t think so. In this case you might use two lists, and get the other value by accessing the the element at the same index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fill your dictionary with lowercase terms.  It will return a capitalized word if you use one.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
dictionary = { 'hello':'hola', 'one':'uno', 'two': 'dos' }

def select( word ):
    lowercase = word .lower()  ##  just test for lowercase values, easier
    caps = word[0] .isupper()  ##  check if first letter caliptalized

    for English, Spanish in dictionary .items():
        if lowercase == English:
            if caps:  return Spanish[0] .upper() +Spanish[1:]  ##  Hola
            else:  return Spanish                              ##  hola

        elif lowercase == Spanish:
            if caps:  return English[0] .upper() +English[1:]  ##  Hello
            else:  return English                              ##  hello

print( select( 'Hola' ) )
```

> Hello

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_key_value(kv, my_dict): # kv stands for key/value, since you don't know if it's key or value.

    # tries to get a value from the dictionary using the kv key.
    # if kv really is a key, my_dict.get(kv) will return the value, otherwise it will return None.
    # so, then we know kv isn't a key in the dictionary.
    if my_dict.get(kv):
        return my_dict.get(kv)

    # so, maybe kv is a value.
    # if kv is in my_dict.values() we then find what's its key using loop.
    elif kv in my_dict.values():
        for item in my_dict.items():
            if item[1] == kv:
                return item[0] # item[0] is the key for the value kv.
```